# JavaScript - Extending built-in objects vs. extending own objects

Tags: javascript, object

I am wondering about the following behaviour of JavaScript.
When I would like to extend a standard built-in object, let's say Math I could simply use a dot to create a method on it.

For example:

```
Math.sum = function(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}
```

Yet, when I want to extend my own Objects I would have to use prototype.

Hope someone can enlighten me.

Comment: What do you mean by "extend"? If you have an object, you can put a property on it directly just like with the Math example. `myObj.sum = ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Yet, when I want to extend my own Objects I would have to use prototype.

No, you don't:

```js
function Example() {
}
Example.sum = function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
};
console.log(Example.sum(1, 2)); // 3
```

When you assign to a property on a *function*, you call it directly on that function (as with your `Math.sum`). These are usually called *static methods*.

When you assign to a property on a function's `prototype` object, you're adding it to the object that will be used as the prototype for the new object if you use that function as a *constructor*, usually via `new`:

```
const e = new Example();
```

These are called *prototype methods*: methods an object inherits from its prototype.

Here's my example above with both a static (`sum`) and a prototype method, using old ES5 syntax:

```js
function Example(x) {
    this.x = x;
}
Example.sum = function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
};
Example.prototype.add = function(y) { // DON'T DO THIS (not in this way), keep reading
    return this.x + y;
};
console.log(Example.sum(1, 2)); // 3
var e = new Example(1);
console.log(e.add(2)); // 3
```

**But**, I strongly recommend that you don't create prototype methods via assignment; instead, use `Object.defineProperty`:

```js
function Example(x) {
    this.x = x;
}
Example.sum = function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
};
Object.defineProperty(Example.prototype, "add", {
    value: function(y) {
        return this.x + y;
    },
    writable: true,
    configurable: true,
    enumerable: false // <== This is the default, but for emphasis
});
console.log(Example.sum(1, 2)); // 3
var e = new Example(1);
console.log(e.add(2)); // 3
```

The reason for doing that is so that the property referring to the function `add` is *non-enumerable* (doesn't show up in `for-in` loops or `Object.keys`, etc.).

---

Taking it further, here in 2020 I'd use `class` syntax (if I wanted a constructor function with a `prototype` object that I used with `new`):

```js
class Example {
    constructor(x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    static sum(a, b) {
        return a + b;
    }
    add(y) {
        return this.x + y;
    }
}
console.log(Example.sum(1, 2)); // 3
const e = new Example(1);
console.log(e.add(2)); // 3
```